# g++ AND gcc is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: c++, gcc

In the command prompt, neither the g++ or gcc are recognized. I have checked the path variable and it seems fine. Shown below.

`C:\WINDOWS\system32; C:\MinGW\bin; C:\Program Files (x86); C:\Program Files`

I have checked other topics about this problem and none of them have worked for me. What could be causing this? And more importantly, what information would you guys need to know to help?

Comment: Are you trying to use MinGW? How did you install it? What's in `C:\MinGW\bin`?

Comment: Yes it is MinGW. I installed it via Code Blocks and the installer on the website. In the \bin, there is mingw-get. The other 2 files are SDL related

Comment: You should have a `gcc.exe` somewhere; I don't know where MinGW puts it or how Code::Blocks might affect that. Try searching for a file with that name on your `C:` drive. And/or read [this web page](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started); perhaps you just haven't finished the installation.

Comment: Managed to fix it myself! I hadn't installed it yet. All fixed! Thanks Keith!

Answer (score 4):

(Copying information from comments.)

The fact that your `C:\MinGW\bin` directory is nearly empty (that's where `gcc.exe` and `g++.exe` should be) indicates that you haven't finished installing MinGW.

See MinGW's [Getting Started page](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started) for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have mingw codeblocks installed, they should add this path to PATH variable in environment variables after a semicolon :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin
```

May vary with your install directory of Codeblocks

Also i have observed that if u have two paths for maybe two gcc installations in PATH variable in environment variables; You will still encounter the msg :

```
gcc is not recognised as an internal or external command
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But I realised, I had installed a wrong version. Re-check the version and make sure it is:
mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc for windows.
The command is :
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc